# Как найти 7 неизвестных?

Tags: математика

Подскажите пожалуйста, как найти подходящие значения для всех семи переменных? там где знак равно там на самом деле может быть "меньше или равно" (<=), пробовал онлайн калькулятор для решения системы линейных уравнений, но либо переменных мало либо не находит

```
absolute(x-y)=2000
absolute((x-y))/x=0.01
absolute(x-a-b)=1000
absolute((x-a-b))/x=0.01
absolute(y-c-d-k)=1000
absolute((y-c-d-k))/y=0.01
```

Comment: у вас 6 уравнений (неравенств, неважно), а переменных говорите 8. Вы можете лишь параметрически выразить какие-то переменные через другие.  Хотя, у вас очень странно. Как минимум, x, y, b, a -вы точно определите из первых четырех уравнений (или неравенств).
А вот последние два уравнения, там аж 4 переменных. Можно выразить d+k, как новую переменную g и решить. Найти точно с, а вот  d, k будут параметром...

Comment: да, ошибся с количеством неизвестных, ну в общем все неизвестные что слева. Я просто даже не знаю как такие задачи решаются помимо решения уравнений или я не так что то делаю

Comment: вам тут пишут что у вас в конце остается два уравнения на 3 переменных, что в принципе не даст вам конкретные значения.

Comment: Ну из первого, подставляя во второе, находим 2000/x == 0.01, т.е. x = 200000. Из первого y — либо 202000, либо 198000. Но! Из 5 и 6 — y == 100000, так что система несовместна...

Comment: аа т.е. система урвнений не умеет решений? а если вместо равно использовать <=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще для первых двух уравнений в случае `<=` решение есть. Чисто програмно можно нарисовать области, где выполняется первое уравнение, где выполняется второе, а потом их пересечение:

```py
# absolute(x-y)<=2000
# absolute((x-y))/x<=0.01

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5000, 5000, 100)
y = np.linspace(-5000, 5000, 100)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
mask1 = np.abs(xx - yy) <= 2000
mask2 = np.abs(xx - yy) / xx <= 0.01
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x=xx[mask1], y=yy[mask1], color='green', alpha=0.1)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x=xx[mask2], y=yy[mask2], color='blue', alpha=0.1)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x=xx[mask1&mask2], y=yy[mask1&mask2], color='cyan', alpha=0.1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это только часть. Картинку можно продолжать бесконечно как вверх вправо так и вниз влево.

А что касается аналитического решения, то для уравнений с модулем вам придётся рассмотреть отдельно случай, когда под модулем получается положительное значение и отдельно когда отрицательное. Хорошо в данном случае, что под модулем в первых двух уравнениях у вас одно и то же выражение.

Answer (score 2):

```
absolute(x-y)=2000
absolute((x-y))/x=0.01
absolute(x-a-b)=1000
absolute((x-a-b))/x=0.01
absolute(y-c-d-k)=1000
absolute((y-c-d-k))/y=0.01
```

Берете первые два уравнения:

```
absolute(x-y)=2000
absolute((x-y))/x=0.01
```

решаете их путем выражения одной переменной через другую.
Находите х и у.
Далее, зная х решаете следующих два уравнения:

```
absolute(x-a-b)=1000
absolute((x-a-b))/x=0.01
```

Также выражаете a через b  и подставляете в другое уравнение.
Все, вы уже нашил х, у, a и b.

Последние два уравнения:

```
absolute(y-c-d-k)=1000
absolute((y-c-d-k))/y=0.01
```

Вы уже знаете y, подставляете сюда.
Далее вы можете найти одну из переменных c, d или k. А остальные две выразить через новую переменную

```
g=d+k.
```

В результате вы найдете все переменные кроме двух.
Если конечно, данная система совместна и допускает общее решение. :)

Comment: пишет что при значениях со знаком равно не имеет решений, а как решить со знаком меньше? это только вычислимым способом через написание программы можно сделать? или есть в математике для этого решения? я там в вопросе писал "на самом деле может быть "меньше или равно" (<=)"

Comment: Подход тот же самый, но с учетом знака меньше. Просто вы столкнетесь с той же проблемой. Если у вас одно неравенство решается так, что y>= 5 (Например), а вот в следующей группе уравнение для решения y<=3 . ВСЕ! приехали, система не имеет решения. Несовместна.

Comment: а если не использовать системы уравнений? ну т.е. вообще никак не решить? не обязательно системой уравнений, я просто не знаю какие способы существуют, может есть полный перебор? какие то вычислительные методы? мне лишь нужно найти подходящие праметры
Или система уравнений чётко доказывает что вообще никаких допустимых значений не может быть?

Comment: Если у вас все эти уравнения связаны между собой и вы не перепутали переменных, нигде не накосячили. Неважно каким способом вы будет решать систему уравнений, хоть перестановкой, хоть перебором. Если она не имеет математического решения, значит не имеет. Может вам описать саму задачу, первоначальную. А потом уже попробовать на базе начальных данных проверить вашу систему уравнений/неравенств. Нужно больше подробностей о начальной постановке задачи